Service Fabric Cluster Lot of crush dumps "Method CompareOrdinal not supported"
Every hour new crach dump.
Service Fabric cluster (Version 10.1.2493.9590)
Nodes 'Standard_D2ds_v4' ubuntu 20_04-lts-gen2
The problem is that .NET ThreadPool.dmp is spamming the logs, which ends up occupying a high amount of memory.
Stacktrace from dump
{"Method CompareOrdinal not supported."}        System.NotSupportedException
 Message    Method CompareOrdinal not supported.    string
 Thread [1971120] .NET ThreadPool Worker    System.Threading.Thread
 StackTrace     System.Diagnostics.StackFrame[]
 [0]    Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitMethodCallNoRewrite(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression call)    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [1]    Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression call) System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [2]    [External Code] System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [3]    Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitBinary(System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression b)    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [4]    [External Code] System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [5]    Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitBinary(System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression b)    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [6]    [External Code] System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [7]    Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitBinary(System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression b)    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [8]    [External Code] System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [9]    Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.Normalize(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> rewrites)   System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [10]   Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient.Bind(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression)   System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [11]   FabricDCA.AzureTableQueryableCsvUploaderDefault.DeleteOldEntities(Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient tableClient, System.DateTime cutoffTime, string partitionKey, FabricDCA.AzureTableQueryableCsvUploaderDefault.StatusEntity statusEntity)    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [12]   FabricDCA.AzureTableQueryableCsvUploaderDefault.DeleteOldLogsHandler(object state)  System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 [13]   [External Code] System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
 InnerException null    
 Additional details     string
 

   at Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitMethodCallNoRewrite(MethodCallExpression call)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.Queryable.ExpressionNormalizer.Normalize(Expression expression, Dictionary`2 rewrites)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient.Bind(Expression expression)
   at Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient.Query[T](Expression`1 filter, Nullable`1 maxPerPage, IEnumerable`1 select, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FabricDCA.AzureTableQueryableCsvUploaderDefault.DeleteOldEntities(TableClient tableClient, DateTime cutoffTime, String partitionKey, StatusEntity statusEntity)
   at FabricDCA.AzureTableQueryableCsvUploaderDefault.DeleteOldLogsHandler(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   at System.Threading.UnmanagedThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteUnmanagedThreadPoolWorkItem(IntPtr callback, IntPtr state)
   at System.Threading.UnmanagedThreadPoolWorkItem.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

**Mitigation of collection dumps **
Set-AzServiceFabricSetting -ResourceGroupName 'API-PROD' -Name 'admiral-prod-api'  -Section 'AzureWinFabCrashDump' -Parameter 'IsEnabled' -Value "false"

Are you using the powershell approach for logs. @ODrobyazko

Jahnavi could you please clarify your question?

May I know for what purpose you are using this Set-AzServiceFabricSetting command. @ODrobyazko

@Jahnavi - I've mentioned  Set-AzServiceFabricSetting just as a step for mitigation gathering crash dumps (we have 100GB dumps/day.
So maybe this info will be useful for someone.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Are you still facing the issue. @ODrobyazko

@Jahnavi yes I have the issue on 3 environments

The same above issue in 3 env? @ODrobyazko

@Jahnavi the same issue on all 3 environments
Here is a sample from one Node
https://prnt.sc/9bzImhiEE63F

Response from Microsoft Service Fabric backend team: issue. which will be fixed in next upcoming release.
you can monitor from this release doc version -https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/blob/master/release_notes/Service_Fabric_ReleaseNotes_101CU6.md
